# "Any epi into a projective object clearly splits"

Tags: category-theory

I am reading *Category theory* by [Steve
Awodey](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/). So that we are all on the
same page regarding the definitions I am using, I will repeat the definitions
described in the book (starting on pg. 28):

> **Definition 2.7** A *split* mono (epi) is an arrow with a left (right)
>   inverse. Given arrows $e : X \rightarrow A$ and $s : A \rightarrow X$ such
>   that $es = 1_A$, the arrow $s$ is called a *section* or *splitting* of $e$,
>   and the arrow $e$ is called a *retraction* of $s$. The object $A$ is called a
>   *retract* of $X$.

...

> An object $P$ is said to be *projective* if for any epi $e : E
> \twoheadrightarrow X$ and arrow $f : P \rightarrow X$ there is some (not
>   necessarily unique) arrow $\overline{f} : P \rightarrow E$ such that $e \circ
> \overline{f} = f$:

[image: Projective Object]

Steve continues, "Any epi into a projective object clearly splits." I'm not
entirely sure what is meant, perhaps $\overline{e} : E \rightarrow P$ such
that:

[image: Split epi]

is an epi *into* a projective object. Then, reconciling with **Definition
2.7**, we have $\overline{f}$ such that $\overline{e}\overline{f} = 1_P$. Is
this correct? At first I thought the statement meant that $e$ splits, but it's
not clear to me how that would be true in general.

P.S. Apologies for the poorly rendered commutative diagrams.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that

> Any epimorphism $e \colon E  \to P$ with $P$ projective admits a section (so is a split epi).

It follows from the projectiveness of $P$ : in the definition, take $X$ to be $P$ and $f$ to be $\mathrm{id}_P$ ; then $\bar f$ is the wanted section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't think about that particular edge case which makes the statement clear. I have tried to edit your post to replace "takes" with "take" but it is refused for being two short an edit. Anyway, it's just pedantry on my part.